# How to install poppler 0.73 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, r, poppler

I am running 18.04 and trying to use version 2.1 of the R package `pdftools`. Some functionality requires `poppler >= 0.73`. (A poppler version requirement is documented in `?pdftools::pdf_data`.)

I obtained `poppler-0.73.0.tar.xz` and `poppler-data-0.4.9.tar.gz` from https://poppler.freedesktop.org/. I extracted, followed the INSTALL instructions, and all seemed to work. I can verify that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so` points to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73`. I'm not sure what else to look for or whether update-alternatives would be helpful.

In R, when I run `pdftools::pdf_data` this happens:

```
> pdf_data(fn)
Error in poppler_pdf_data(loadfile(pdf), opw, upw) : 
  pdf_data() requires poppler >= 0.73. You have 0.62.0
```

Other functions in `pdftools` work, but `pdf_data` is documented to required `poppler >= 0.73`. I'm wondering what else I need to do to have 0.73 recognized.

EDIT: Following helpful suggestions at [Installing poppler-0.62.0 on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983716/installing-poppler-0-62-0-on-ubuntu-16-04), I ran `apt-cache policy poppler-0.73` and got:

```
poppler-0.73:
  Installed: 20190125-0.73
  Candidate: 20190125-0.73
  Version table:
 *** 20190125-0.73 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This seems to suggest that 0.73 is installed.

The output of `apt-cache policy r-base-core` is

```
r-base-core:
  Installed: 3.5.2-1bionic
  Candidate: 3.5.2-1bionic
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.5.1-2bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.1-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.0-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.osuosl.org/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Which version of R do you use? Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base-core` to the question. I have successfully installed `pdftools` it with R 3.4 from official Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repositories. I have installed Poppler with `sudo apt install libpoppler-cpp-dev`.

Comment: @N0rbert I have edited the question both to add the `apt-cache policy` output, and to clarify that `pdftools` mostly works, but `pdf_data` does not. It works as documented. My guess is that `pdf_data` will not work for you either.

Comment: I do not see the `pdf_data` in the [list of R-CRAN packages](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html). What is exact name of it?

Comment: @N0rbert `pdf_data` is a function in `pdftools`. See the third paragraph of my post, `pdftools::pdf_data`

Comment: Solved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it working we need to do the following:

1. Uninstall the `libpoppler-cpp-dev` package

   ```
   sudo apt purge libpoppler-cpp-dev
   ```
2. Compile and install Poppler 0.73 with `checkinstall` (as you already did) to the `/usr/local`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev cmake checkinstall
   sudo apt-get build-dep libpoppler-cpp-dev

   cd ~/Downloads
   wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.73.0.tar.xz
   tar -xf poppler-0.73.0.tar.xz
   cd poppler-0.73.0

   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ..
   sudo checkinstall make install
   ```
3. Define the environment variable *R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH* to inform R about the Poppler libraries in `/usr/local/lib`:

   ```
   echo "export R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" >> .bashrc
   ```
4. Compile the `pdftools` R-package inside `R`-shell:

   ```
   install.packages("pdftools")
   ```
5. Test it from `R`-shell with any pdf-file

   > ```
   > > pdftools::pdf_data(pdf="/usr/share/cups/data/default.pdf")
   > [1]]
   > [1] width  height x      y      space  text  
   > <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
   > ```

---

Note: I tested this method on my clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM with both R 3.4 and 3.5.2 from R-shell and from RStudio.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Excellent instructions. In my case the missing step was setting `R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then reinstalling pdftools.

Comment: Could you please provide me some help? Im running Debian 9 and I have done all steps above and i am getting errors when trying to install the package `pdftool`s in R.  `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pdftools’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/admonda/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-pdftools/00new/pdftools/libs/pdftools.so':
  libpoppler-cpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed`

Comment: Debian 9 is off-topic here. You have to adapt above answer on your own

Answer (score 8):

I created a PPA with backports of Poppler 0.74.0 for **Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)** and **Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)**. This is now the recommended way to update your poppler.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/poppler
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libpoppler-cpp-dev
```

Comment: Use: sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/poppler

Comment: thanks Jeroen for the PPA, very much appreciated!!