# Unable to complete pdftools installation Ubuntu 18.04 for R supporting readtext

Tags: software-installation, r, poppler

I read the post [How install poppler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112856/how-to-install-poppler-0-73-on-ubuntu-18-04) and was hopeful regarding my own difficulty, but no dice.

I am running R under Anaconda on a Ubuntu 18.04 Precision laptop. I wanted to install readtext (R package) to support some corpora linguistics study and attempted that from R terminal window. I had already installed quanteda without a problem so was surprised when readtext tripped on a pdftools requirement which in turn tripped

```
cannot find -lpoppler-cpp
```

I had already installed and uninstalled libpoppler-cpp-dev several times using

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpoppler-cpp-dev
```

That installed ok

```
libpoppler-cpp-dev is already the newest version (0.74.0-bionic0)
```

When I attempt the readtext install from R (again, running under Anaconda, which might be problem), it arrives at the pdftools install and finds the local pkg-config info

> - installing *source* package ‘pdftools’ ...
>   ** package ‘pdftools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation Found pkg-config cflags and libs! Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/poppler/cpp -I/usr/include/poppler Using
>   PKG_LIBS=-lpoppler-cpp

But then cannot find it:

> /home/dalton/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> cannot find -lpoppler-cpp collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [/home/dalton/anaconda3/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6:
> pdftools.so] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pdftools’
>
> - removing ‘/home/dalton/anaconda3/lib/R/library/pdftools’

When I check pkg-config myself:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs poppler-cpp
```

-I/usr/include/poppler/cpp -I/usr/include/poppler -lpoppler-cpp

I indeed find the same information the installer in R finds. When I chased down poppler with a system grep:

```
ls --recursive | grep -E "poppler"
```

I do not find poppler-cpp, though I find libpoppler-cpp-dev and other libpoppler-cpp files/folders. However, if I interrogate pkg-config:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libpoppler-cpp-dev
```

It tells me

Package libpoppler-cpp-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpoppler-cpp-dev.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. No package 'libpoppler-cpp-dev' found.

I used the PPA with backports of Poppler 0.74.0 for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) recommended by @jeroen in the cited SE post above, but it appears there is some confusion between the Ubuntu proper and Anaconda R, since the R install is looking for poppler-cpp, but libpoppler-cpp-dev seems to be the appropriate target. Because I am running R under Anaconda, my system seems unaware of R:

```
apt-cache policy r-base-core
```

returns

> r-base-core:
> Installed: (none)
> Candidate: 3.4.4-1ubuntu1
> Version table:
> 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
> 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages

I realize this is all somewhat of a mess, but I am hoping someone will recognize an obvious problem and tell me what to hack up, e.g., modify the poppler-cpp.pc to point at the new library or the like.

Comment: Remember Ubuntu package names and pkg-config package names are not the same: the pkg-config file provided by `libpopplar-cpp-dev` is named `poppler-cpp.pc` indicating that you'd query it as `pkg-config --cflags --libs poppler-cpp`

Comment: ... I guess the question I'd be asking is what the anaconda gcc's library search paths are (using `path/to/anaconda/gcc -print-search-dirs` for example)

Comment: @steeldrive Thanks for those comments. I will update here if make any progress.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remain within the Anaconda/conda environment, since R is running there and this is a bit of an island within the surrounding Ubuntu sea (if the metaphor is not making you seasick). Just do

```
conda install -c conda-forge poppler
```

That took quite a while to finish, since the initial two attemtps to "solve the environment" failed, but conda finally tried another repodata source and succeeded:

> 

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
certifi-2019.9.11          |           py37_0         147 KB  conda-forge
conda-4.10.1               |   py37h89c1867_0         3.1 MB  conda-forge
openjpeg-2.3.1             |       h21c5421_1         469 KB  conda-forge
poppler-0.65.0             |       h581218d_1         1.3 MB
poppler-data-0.4.10        |                0         3.8 MB  conda-forge
python_abi-3.7             |          1_cp37m           4 KB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         8.7 MB
```

etc., ending with the blessed

> Executing transaction: done

Then I opened a terminal window and started R:

> dalton@dalton-Precision-3541:$ R

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)

and installed pdftools:

```
> install.packages("pdftools")
```

> - installing *source* package ‘pdftools’ ...
>   ** package ‘pdftools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation
>   Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
>   Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/poppler/cpp -I/usr/include/poppler
>   Using PKG_LIBS=-lpoppler-cpp

etc. For those are interested, the Anaconda library files were in areas like

> -lpoppler-cpp -L/home/dalton/anaconda3/lib/R/lib -lR

In other words, after the conda installation of poppler, my R install of pdftools could find poppler-cpp. pdftools completed:

> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path

- DONE (pdftools)

I then was able to complete my original task of installing readtext, which required poppler and pdftools:

```
install.packages("readtext")
```

> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path

- DONE (readtext)

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmpxksozx/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

> library(readtext)

All is good with the world, the convoluted world of Anaconda/conda within Ubuntu. It is a great environment for scientific and academic computing, once you figure out how to communicate.