# How to downgrade poppler-utils version from 0.74 to 0.62 in ubuntu 18?

Tags: python, downgrade

I installed poppler-utils on ubuntu 18 using the following command:

```
apt-get install poppler-utils
```

It automatically installed version 0.74.0. I want to downgrade it to 0.62.0. I've already followed this tutorial, but pdftohtml isn't working: [Installing poppler-0.62.0 on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983716/installing-poppler-0-62-0-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)

Any simple way to downgrade?

Comment: 0.74.0 is in 19.04. If you are running 18.* and you get 0.74.0, it means you have done something weird with your repositories.

Comment: Maybe. But the question is, how to downgrade?

Comment: Well, firstly, where does this 0.74 come from? Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy poppler-utils`.